# SQL local server disappear after uninstall SSMS 2014 and install SSMS 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017

I am planning to install the latest version SQL Server Management Studio SSMS 2017 and trying to use the same local server name which was on SSMS 2014.

So I uninstalled SSMS 2014 then install SSMS 2017. After the installation complete, I am not able to login to my local server by using the same credential.

I have checked SQL Server 2017 Configuration Manager, there is nothing under the SQL Server services.

[image: SQL Server 2017 Config manager]

And there is nothing under the registered servers.

[image: registered servers]

Need help to retrieve my local server name, or guide how to recreate a new server name.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you uninstalled SSMS 2014 and not SQL Server 2014? The fact that you cannot see the instance in th configuration Manager strongly suggests so.

Comment: I think I uninstalled SQL Server 2014, which means I need install SQL server 2017 rather than SSMS 2017. Can fix the issue?

Comment: That depends, do you have licenses for 2017? SSMS 2017 is compatible with SQL SERVER 2008 -2017, so you can use it against a 2014 instance. Either way though, you won't get the databases you uninstalled back.

Comment: I don't have the Licenses for 2017, but I can reinstall 2014 back. When I am trying to load the database created from SSMS 2017 in 2014, the version is compatible. That is why I am trying to uninstall 2014 and install 2017.

Comment: If you don't have licenses for 2017, and do for 2014, why are you installing 2017? That would be a breach of the license agreement. SSMS is free, but SQL Server (apart from Express and Developer) is not. If you have purchased licences for 2014 they aren't transferable to 2017.

Comment: Originally, I am trying to load the database created in SSMS 2017 into my sql server 2014, and it states version is incompatible, then I uninstalled sql server 2014, and installed SSMS 2017. That caused what happening.

Comment: If you create a database in SSMS 2017, on a 2014 instance, it'll work on any 2014 instance (provided it has any required CU's/SP's installed). I suspect you installed SQL server 2017 and SSMS 2017 and are now trying to attach that database to a 2014 instance. Databases aren't back compatible. You'll need to script everything out to get it on a 2014 instance. At this stage, however, I'm really playing the guessing game, as a lot of what you're saying doesn't really make sense; or conflicts with previous comments. You seem to be mixing up SSMS and SQL Server too, further confusing matters.

Comment: I suggest taking a step back, reading your comments, and mine, then probably a asking a new question, that is far clearer, and (possibly) deleting this one.

Comment: Yes. you are correct. After I installed the SQL server 2017, it fixed the issue. database created in SSMS 2017 worked with SQL server 2017 bu not SQL server 2014.Thanks for help.